# How to update a specific div with view file content?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I include some content in php/symfony like this:

```
<div id='content'>
  <?php include_partial( 'course/content.php', array("param1" => "1", "param2" => "2") ); ?>
</div>
```

Now I want to update this content again via AJAX using jQuery.

How can I update `content` div again by calling `course/content.php` using jQuery on some jQuery event?

Thanks

Comment: This is an overly broad question. We're here to help with problems you're having with code you've at least attempted to write for yourself, not to write the code for you from scratch. You'll also need to nail down the specific requirements, such as **which** event you want to perform the AJAX call on (a particular button being clicked, a form element having its value changed, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the .load event or else .get:

```
$('#content').load('course/content.php');
```

Or a .get example:

```
$.get('course/content.php', function (data){
    $('#content').html(data);
});
```

Comment: how to pass data `array("param1" => "1", "param2" => "2")`

Comment: in that case use .post and you can pass an object as the second parameter with function being the third.

Answer (score 2):

Use the jquery ajax method... **data** (call it what you like) is your repsonse from the query

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "content/content.php",
  data: myarray,
  success: function(data){
    $('#content').html(data);
  }
});
```

for more info on various methods, calls etc go to [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({type : 'POST',url : 'course/content.php', data: {par1:val1, par2: val2},success : function(data){
                                                    $('#content').append(data);
                                                },

});
```